# How do I pass data between activities using Jetpack Compose in Android with Kotlin?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a mainactivity in which, after pressing the button, a script is triggered that transfers to another activity in which the text is displayed

This is the code in MainActivity

```
var textTitle by rememberSaveable  { mutableStateOf("") }
Scaffold(topBar = {
                    TopAppBar(title = {
                        Text("Hello")
                    }
                    )})
                {
                    it->
                    Box(modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(it)
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        , contentAlignment = Alignment.Center)
                    {
                        LazyColumn()
                        {
                            item {
                                OutlinedTextField(value = textTitle, onValueChange = { textTitle = it.take(60) } )
                            }
                            item {
                                Button(onClick = {
                                    val navigate = Intent(this@MainActivity, MainActivity2::class.java)
                                    intent.putExtra("title", textTitle)
                                    startActivity(navigate)
                                })
                                {

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This is the code in MainActivity2

```
val textTitle = intent.getStringExtra("title")
Text(
        text = "Hello ${textTitle.toString()}!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
```

When switching to MainActivity2, I'm waiting for the Hello null text

I watched the video (two weeks ago) and sites and many cite this method and this method works for them. They fill out a text field, then click a button and the text they entered is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

```
Button(onClick = {
                                    val navigate = Intent(this@MainActivity, MainActivity2::class.java)
                                    intent.putExtra("title", textTitle)
                                    startActivity(navigate)
                                }
```

after you create `navigate`, you are using `.putExtra` on an intent object that is not related to the `navigate` you are using to change activity. That's why the data you are trying to send isn't received in the new activity.